# If Type.IsGenericParameter == true, will Type.ContainsGenericParameters == true always?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0, .net-4.6

If `type.IsGenericParameter == true` then is it guaranteed that `type.ContainsGenericParameter == true` for the same type?

Is there an example where this is NOT the case?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.containsgenericparameters?view=netframework-4.8) for the `ContainsGenericParameters` property:

**`true` if the [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) object is itself a generic type parameter** or has type parameters for which specific types have not been supplied; otherwise, `false`.

Comment: UGH - I should have seen that.  Too many browser tabs open =)  Can you post as the answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.containsgenericparameters?view=netframework-4.8) for the `ContainsGenericParameters` property:

> **Property Value**
>   `true` if the [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) object is itself a generic type parameter or has type parameters for which specific types have not been supplied; otherwise, `false`.

So, yes, it sounds like if one of those properties returns true, so will the other. :)

Comment: In fact, if you decompile you'll see the following in ContainsGenericParameters: `if (this.IsGenericParameter) return true;`